# Why can't I specify where I want my Kotlin file to be destinated in Android Studio?

Tags: android, android-studio, intellij-idea, kotlin, android-studio-3.0

my problem is the following:

I'm using Android Studio 3.0.1 and I'm trying to be as fast as possible on creating new files (using **MVP** can be a challenge in Kotlin).

For example, when in Java you find this:
[image]

Then if you click (according to your computer) on Option + Enter, I have the option to create my interface:

[image]

I can choose the package and the folder where it will be placed:
[image]

But when I'm with Kotlin:

It just offers me to choose the class container (and I want to import it, setting up externally)

[image]

Is there any reason why Android Studio is not equipped with this?

Answer (score 0):

You do need a second step currently, but it's very simple: create it in `MyListActivity.kt` and then `Option+Enter` on the created interface will give you option to move it to a separate file. And look on https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/ if there is an issue for this yet.

Comment: Even move just moves it to its own class, but same package. I found this bug report for this https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-19924